# Can anyone explain the output of following statement?

Tags: c, printf

I am not able to understand the following statement written in C:

```
printf("%d", printf("%d", printf("%s", "I love c programming")));
```

Is it valid to write such statement in C?

When I run it, I get the output:

```
I love c programming202
```

Can anyone explain the output of this statement?

Comment: Looks valid to me. What's your problem with the code?

Comment: @EOF,i not understand what output will the above given statement will show??

Comment: Yes, it's valid. As far as what it does, read the documentation on `printf`, particularly its return value.

Comment: What did you get when you ran it?  Which part of the output didn't you understand?  How could you improve the format strings so it is clearer?  What is the sequence in which the output strings appear?

Answer (score 4):

`printf` returns an `int` indicating an error or containing the number of characters written. So, because `%d` is the format string for an `int`, this nesting is completely valid.

Your output is `"I love c programming202"`. So let's break that down:

1. The innermost `printf` prints `"I love c programming"`. This is 20 characters, which `printf` returns.
2. The second innermost `printf` prints `20` because that's the return value of the previous `printf`.
3. The outer `printf` prints `2` because `20` has 2 characters.

Comment: ,the output of above statement is coming as:I love c programming202.Can u please explain me the output??

Comment: @sagg1295 Added. Add the output to your question, not hidden in some comment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `printf` is a function which returns an integer value (the number of characters printed, including the \n at the end)

Answer (score 1):

printf return value:                                                                                      Upon successful return, these functions return the number of characters printed (excluding the null byte used to end output to strings).

```
printf("%d",printf("%d",printf("%s","I love c programming")));

<=>

int ret;                                                                                       
// output "I love c programming" => ret = 20                                                    
ret = printf("%s","I love c programming");·                                                    
// ret = 20 => output "20" => ret = 2                                                          
ret = printf("%d", ret);                                                                       
print("%d", ret); // ret = 2 => output "2"                                                         

// => I love c programming202
```